# Can't get index position from list of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the position of a dataframe from a list of dataframes, by using the built-in method index in python. My code is below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([4, 5, 6])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([7, 8, 9])   

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in dfs:
    print(dfs.index(df))
```

Where instead of getting the expected 0, 1 and 2, it only returns 0, followed by ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know this error typically comes from data frames comparison, and I've tried adding the .all() but to no avail.

If I change the list to something like a list of strings, ints or a mix of them, no problem whatsoever.

I've tried searching around but found nothing on this specific error.

I know I can easily add an extra variable that keeps on adding 1 for each iteration of the list, but I'd really like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried with enumerate() ? ie `for i, df in enumerate(dfs): print(i)`

Comment: This is not pandas related question. It is simply Python question.

Comment: I was hesitant to place the pandas tag, but the error does direct to a DataFrame issue, hence why i added the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you can use `enumerate` to do what you want.

As to why what you're trying isn't working:

`list.index(item)` looks for the first element of the list such that `element == item`. As an example consider `df = dfs[0]`. When we call `dfs.index(df)`, we first check whether `df ==` the first element of `dfs`. In other words we are checking whether `df == df`. If you type this into your interpreter you will find that this gives you a `DataFrame` of `True`s. This is a `DataFrame` object -- but what Python wants to know is whether it should consider this object as `True` or not. So it needs to convert this `DataFrame` into a single `bool`. It tries to do this via `bool(df == df)`, which relies on `pandas` implementing a method that converts any `DataFrame` into a `bool`. However there is no such method, and for good reason -- because the correct way to do this is ambiguous. So at this point `pandas` raises the error that you see.

In summary: for `index` to make sense, the objects must have some notion of equality (`==`), but `DataFrame`s don't have such a notion, for good reason.

If in a future problem you need to find the index of a `DataFrame` within a list of `DataFrame`s, you first have to decide on a notion of equality. One sensible such notion is if all the values are the same. Then you can define a function like:

```
def index(search_dfs, target_df):
    for i, search_df in enumerate(search_dfs):
        if (search_df.values == target_df.values).all():
            return i
    return ValueError('DataFrame not in list')

index(dfs, df[2])
Out: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` :

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Because essentially you are trying to find in a list a dataframe that is equal to a dataframe:

for df in dfs:
    for i,d in enumerate(dfs):
        if d==df: print(i)

This gives you the same error message.

Comment: The .index only returns a boolean say df.column_name("abc"), this will return True against every index where the value of column_name is "abc" in dataframe df and False for the rest. So to retrieve the value of index as well, you can use df.column_name("abc").values

Comment: I think you're mixing the built-in index method in python with the .Index command in pandas.

Comment: Yes, seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print(i)
```

And this is not a pandas related question. It's simply Python question.

Comment: Looks fairly like a pandas question to me.

Comment: Because you want to get the index of items in a list which is Python.

Comment: Honestly I don't think you've really read the question properly, they are more interested as to why `index` failed and why `pandas` threw that `pandas` error.

Comment: Ok, I understood now what information you were actually looking for.