# How to append a Series to a Dataframe contained within a list of Dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of *k* empty DataFrames, but I need to access those DataFrames individually to append a selected Series object. For instance, let's say I want to append column *i* in df1 to the ith Dataframe in my list of clusters. How can I do this?

So far I've only found the following but it hasn't addressed this particular problem: [Can't get index position from list of Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383473/cant-get-index-position-from-list-of-dataframes)

```py
k_clusters = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(k)]

for i in df1 
   k_clusters[i].append(df[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this seem like a solution:

```py
k_clusters = [pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6], "c": [7,8,9]}) for _ in range(3)]

# Picking a dataframe to iterate
df1 = k_clusters[0]

# Enumerate over the columns and add the column to the other dataframes
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    k_clusters[i]["d"] = df1[col]

# Print the first cluster
k_clusters[0]

Out[13]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  2
2  3  6  9  3
```

I have introduced a new column called "d" because I am using the same columns for all my clusters. You can adapt it to your columns.